# understanding Android Services and threads

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have doubts when it comes to Services.

I know the service runs in the background, but I thought you necessarily needed to create a thread within the service, otherwise it would block the main thread and you would get an ANR error.

I thought I got it! But then I read this in the Android Developer guide:

> …if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the user interacts with an activity from the same application, the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application performance, you should start a new thread inside the service.>

The paragraph mentions "intensive or blocking operations", but doesn’t mention an ANR error, it mentions performance.  So how a service works?

Supposing an Activity starts a Service. Does the Service run by default in the background of the main thread? Meaning that you can still use your activity while the service is running, but since your Activity and the Service are sharing the main thread’s resources, it would slow down the performance of your activity, and if Service is doing CPU intensive work, it could leave no resources for the activity to use, and eventually you would get an ANR error.

The best practice (but not necessarily, if the service is doing light work) would be to start a new Thread within the Service, now the Activity and the Service are using their own thread’s resources. Then you could close your activity, but Android keeps the service thread alive.

Is that it? Thanks =)

Comment: Services run in the one and only main thread. They do nothin in background. Blocking in a service while an Activity is active will ANR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought you necessarily needed to create a thread within the service, otherwise it would block the main thread and you would get an ANR error.

Correct.

> The paragraph mentions "intensive or blocking operations", but doesn’t mention an ANR error, it mentions performance.

Feel free to file a bug report at http://b.android.com to get them to improve this portion of the documentation. :-)

> Does the Service run by default in the background of the main thread?

The lifecycle methods of a `Service`, such as `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()`, are called on the main application thread. Some services, like `IntentService`, will provide you with a background thread (e.g., for `onHandleIntent()`), but that is specific to that particular subclass of `Service`.

> and eventually you would get an ANR error.

Yes.

> The best practice (but not necessarily, if the service is doing light work) would be to start a new Thread within the Service, now the Activity and the Service are using their own thread’s resources. Then you could close your activity, but Android keeps the service thread alive.

Basically, yes. Here, "light work" should be less than a millisecond or so. Also, some things that you might do are naturally asynchronous (e.g., playing a song via `MediaPlayer`), so it may be that the `Service` itself does not need its own thread, because something else that it is using is doing the threading.

Comment: Ohh, I think I get it. Just like @zapl and you said. By default, Services do nothing background, the callbacks run on the main thread and if the services work takes more than 5 seconds, you get an ANR. 
But a Service that doesn’t run on the background by default, makes no sense to me. The reason is that you could create an application that is entirely a Service, then it will have all the main thread to itself.

Comment: @ILovemyPoncho: "The reason is that you could create an application that is entirely a Service" -- that's not really practical. As I noted in my answer, a service sometimes coordinates things that are themselves asynchronous, and so we do not necessarily need our own thread. Also, some services might have different threading needs -- `IntentService` offers only one thread, but another service might need a thread pool. Hence, `Service` leaves threading up to us, to choose something that fits our needs, rather than forcing a particular threading model.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense than what I thought haha. That solves my doubts. Thanks